# Cannot get my boolean values to work

Tags: boolean, driver, equals, temperature

So I'm supposed to create a program that sets temperatures to celsius and farenheit. In it I create an equals method. Then I'm to create a driver that runs it and tests temperatures to see if they are equal, or not, using the equals method. I cannot get the correct boolean values, it just keeps spitting out false. Hitting a wall here.  Code is as follows:

public class Temperature
{
    public enum Scale{ CELSIUS, FARENHEIT};

```
public static final double DEFAULT_DEGREES = 0.0;

private double temperature;
private Scale scale;

public Temperature()
{
    this(Temperature.DEFAULT_DEGREES);
}//default

public Temperature(double newTemperature)
{
    this(newTemperature, Scale.CELSIUS);
}//ending bracket of constructor double

public Temperature(Scale newScale)
{
    this(0, newScale);
}//end of constructor scale

public Temperature(double newTemperature, Scale newScale)
{
    this.setTemperature(newTemperature);
    this.setScale(newScale);
}//end bracket of constructor degrees and scale

public Scale getScale()
{
    return this.scale;
}//end of method getScale

public void setScale(Scale newScale)
{
    this.scale=newScale;
}//end of method setScale

public double getTemperature()
{
    return this.temperature;
}//ending bracket of metho getTemperature

public void setTemperature(double newTemperature)
{
    if(newTemperature < Temperature.DEFAULT_DEGREES)
    {
        this.temperature=Temperature.DEFAULT_DEGREES;
    }
    else
    {
        this.temperature = newTemperature;
    }//ending of if
}//ending bracket of method setTemperature

public double getTemperatureInFarenheit()
{
    double rv;

    if(this.getScale() == Scale.CELSIUS)
    {
        rv= this.getTemperature();
    }
    else
    {
        rv = ((this.getTemperature()* 1.8) + 32);
    }//end of if

    return rv;
}//end of bracket of method getweightinfarenheit


public double getTemperatureInCelsius()
{
    double rv;

    if(this.getScale() == Scale.FARENHEIT)
    {
        rv = this.getTemperature();
    }
    else
    {
        rv= ((this.getTemperature()- 32) * 0.5556);
    }

    return rv;
}//end of method gettemperatureincelsius

public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
{
    boolean rv = false;

    if(otherObject instanceof Temperature)
    {

        Temperature otherTemperature = (Temperature)otherObject;

        if((this.getTemperature()== otherTemperature.getTemperature())
        &&(this.getScale()== otherTemperature.getScale()))
        {
            rv = true;
        }//end of nested if
    }//end of if

    return rv;
}//end of bracket method equals
```

}//ending of class

This is my driver:

public class TemperatureDriver
{

```
public static void main(String[]args)
{


    Temperature w1 = new Temperature();
    w1.setTemperature(32);
    w1.setScale(Temperature.Scale.FARENHEIT);
    Temperature w2 = new Temperature();
    w2.setTemperature(0);
    w2.setScale(Temperature.Scale.CELSIUS);

    System.out.println(w1.equals(w2));

    Temperature w3 = new Temperature();
    w3.setTemperature(-40.0);
    w3.setScale(Temperature.Scale.FARENHEIT);
    Temperature w4 = new Temperature();
    w4.setTemperature(-40.0);
    w4.setScale(Temperature.Scale.CELSIUS);

    System.out.println(w3.equals(w4));

    Temperature w5 = new Temperature();
    w5.setTemperature(212);
    w5.setScale(Temperature.Scale.FARENHEIT);
    Temperature w6 = new Temperature();
    w6.setTemperature(100);
    w6.setScale(Temperature.Scale.CELSIUS);

    System.out.println(w5.equals(w6));




}//end of method main
```

}//end of class Temperaturedriver

Comment: rather than testing for equality when you do conversions with decimal approximations, it might make more sense to see if two things differ by less than epsilon. Also, I find the GetTemperatureinCelsius puzzling, because it converts when the scale is celsius but not Fahrenheit. Is that backwards?

Comment: Unfortunately the professor I have is insisting we test for equality when we do conversions. As for the getTemperatureInCelsius question, if you look above that theres ...InFarenheit above it, should I put those as one block and make it an if else statement?

Comment: So I think then that the 1.8 will work (though I might prefer multiplying by 9 and dividing by 5), but I think you need *5 and divide by 9 where you have 0.5556, because things will only be almost equal otherwise. I have no problem with the testing for equality, though. I was suggesting you implement your equals by testing if the absolute value of temperature difference is less than epsioln rather than using == on the reals.

Comment: Also, no problem with two functions for getTemperatureIn,. What bothered my is that it seems to me that you are converting when the scale is the desired scale and leaving things alone when you should be converting. That is if your scale is celsius and you want to get in Celsius, you should return the temeprature.

Comment: Oh, but there is a bigger problem in your equals. It insists that to be equal two temperatures must have the same scale. What you want to say is that there getTemperatureinCelsius are the same.

Comment: Oh WOW! I have no Idea how I missed that. You are a life saver!  Thank you for the second set of eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So there are a couple of issues I see. First, in your implementation of 
getTemperatureInCelsius()

```
if(this.getScale() == Scale.FARENHEIT)
```

should be, I think,

```
if(this.getScale() == Scale.CELSIUS)
```

and vice versa for your implementation of getTemperatureInFarenheit.

Once those are fixed, I think the primary issue with your equals is it insists scales be the same. Where you have

```
if((this.getTemperature()== otherTemperature.getTemperature())
    &&(this.getScale()== otherTemperature.getScale()))
```

instead should be

```
if(this.getTemperatureInFarenheit()== otherTemperature.getTemperatureInFahrenheit())
```

where I am deliberately comparing in Farenheit to avoid the rounding in your celsius conversion factor. That will probably make equals work (once the fix I mentioned for getTemperatureInFarenheit is made).

I still think I would feel better about saying something like

```
if(Math.abs(this.getTemperatureInFarenheit()-otherTemperature.getTemperatureInFahrenheit())<0.001)
```

than what I suggested above, and I would try that if the above fails.

Comment: I don't know why it didn't occur to me that the decimal value is what was throwing it off the whole time!  I appreciate the help.